# What does "kettle cooked" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

What does "kettle cooked" mean? "Kettle" is the thing with a spout you boil water in, as far as I know. You don't boil potatoes to get potato chips, do you, though?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While *teakettle* is the most common association with kettle, a [**kettle**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kettle) can be any metal container in which food or liquid is heated. It's a less common word for pot. There are also industrial kettles, which are essentially large vats.

[Here](https://www.engineeringworldchannel.com/potato-chips/) is a link to an engineeringworld article about how potato chips are made. The distinction between kettle-cooked and modern standard chips seems to be that kettle-cooked chips are fried in batches in the kettle, while modern standard chips go through a "continuous" fry process on a conveyor belt.

Comment: One day our nurseries will ring with the sound of "Polly put the kettle on - we'll all have chips."

Comment: Sergey, it's advertising. Ignore it.

Comment: The difference to the person buying them is that kettle-cooked chips have a different texture; they're crunchier.

Comment: There's also "kettle corn", a distinct variety of popcorn.

Comment: @Hearth And it's unclear whether this is *because* they're kettle-cooked, or the potatoes are cut thicker, or something else. "Kettle cooked" may be as much a marketing term for *one particular possible style* of kettle cooked chips as it is a description of the manufacturing process.

Comment: To me, "kettle" implies rounded sides, so that the opening is smaller than the maximum width (whereas a "pot" typically has straight sides.) Is this actually implied or is it just me?

Comment: @NickMatteo I agree, though they probably use something more akin to a cauldron to cook potato chips. But that was probably rejected by the advertising dept.